# comparing two objects does not give correct results

Tags: javascript

i am trying to compare two objects. The ages are different but still  says they are same..
here is my code

```
var personA =
    {
        name: "Josh Kloss",
        age: 33
    }
var personmB =
{
    name: 'Josh Kloss',
    age: 43
}

function compareTwoPeople(a, b) {

    var person1 = Object.keys(a);
    var person2 = Object.keys(b);
    if (person1.length !== person2.length) {
        console.log("They are not same");
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < person1.length; i++) {
            if (person1[i] === person2[i]) {
                console.log("They are  same");
            }
        }
    }

}

compareTwoPeople(personA, personmB);
```

How can i compare these two object...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close, just need to tidy up the comparison a little bit to get at the object value using the key and the iterator.

```
var personA =
    {
        name: "Josh Kloss",
        age: 33
    };
var personB =
{
    name: 'Josh Kloss',
    age: 43
};

function compare(a, b) {
  var aKeys = Object.keys(a),
      bKeys = Object.keys(b);

  if(aKeys.length != bKeys.length) return false;

  for(var i = 0; i < aKeys.length; i++) {
    if(a[aKeys[i]] != b[bKeys[i]]) return false;
  }

  return true;

}

compare(personA, personB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking up `person1[i]` which will be `[ 'name', 'age' ][0]`, which is `'name'`, the key name. It's the same for both objects. The quick solution to your question is:

```
if (a[person1[i]] !== b[person2[i]]) {
    console.log("They are not the same");
    return;
}
```

However this is not a great equality test, because your objects could both have two keys, but different keys.

Comment: I think if the key order does not matter, using "a[person1[i]] !== b[person1[i]]" would be better

Comment: @Andy can you give me the full code. i am a beginner here.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [*Array.prototype.every*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.every) for the property value comparison part. It's efficient as it returns false at the first mismatch rather than going over all the properties when it doesn't have to:

```js
var personA = {name: "Josh Kloss", age: 33};
var personB = {name: 'Josh Kloss', age: 43};

// Return true if objects a and b have the same properties
// with the same values. Otherwise, false.
function compareTwoPeople(a, b) {

  var person1 = Object.keys(a);
  var person2 = Object.keys(b);

  // Use first test to initialise result
  var result = person1.length === person2.length;

  // If passed the first test, do the second
  if (result) {

    // Use every to test each value, returns false at first mismatch
    result = person1.every(function(prop){
      return a[prop] === b[prop];
    });
  }
  return result;
}

document.write('Are they the same? ' + compareTwoPeople(personA, personB));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can compare by going through each properties,

```
var personA =
    {
        name: "Josh Kloss",
        age: 33
    };

var personB =
{
    name: 'Josh Kloss',
    age: 43
};

function getObjectSize(obj){
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
}

function isObjectsEqual(a, b){

    //check objects has equal length
    if(getObjectSize(a) !== getObjectSize(b)){
        return false;
    }

    //check properties are equal
    for (var key in a) {

        if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)){

            if(a[key] != b[key]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

isObjectsEqual(personA, personB); //test function
```